# Enable and disable jquery knob dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-knob

I'm using the excellent [jQuery knob plugin](http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/). However, I need to dynamically enable/disable the element depending on user input. There is support for having a `disabled` state on page load which have the effect that no mouse (or touch) events are bound to the canvas element. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue, that is, how to (after page load) bind and unbind these mouse event listeners?

Ideally I would like to do something like this (on a disabled knob)

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $('.knob').enable();
});
```

**Edit:** 
I ended up rewriting the source which binds/unbinds the mouse and touch events. The solution is not perfect so I leave the question open if someone perhaps have a better (cleaner) solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**html**

```
<input class="knobSlider" data-readOnly="true">
<button id="testBtn">clickHere</button>
```

**script**

*in doc ready,*

```
$(".knobSlider").knob();
$("#testBtn").click(function(){
    $(".knobSlider").siblings("canvas").remove();
    if($(".knobSlider").attr("data-readOnly")=='true'){
        $(".knobSlider").unwrap().removeAttr("data-readOnly readonly").data("kontroled","").data("readonly",false).knob();
    }
    else{
        $(".knobSlider").unwrap().attr("data-readOnly",true).data("kontroled","").data("readonly",true).knob();
    }
});
```

For reference you can use my jsfiddle link > http://jsfiddle.net/EG4QM/ (check this in firefox, because of some external resource load problem in chrome)

Answer (score 4):

If someone doesn't like how the accepted answer destroys and recreates the internal canvas element, then checkout my approach:

https://jsfiddle.net/604kj5g5/1/

Essentially, check the `draw()` implementation (I also recommend listening on value changes in the `draw` method instead of the `change` and `release`, which work for and `click` and `mousewheel` events respectively, which imo is inconvenient).

```
var $input = $("input");

var knobEnabled = true;
var knobPreviousValue = $input.val();

$input.knob({
  draw: function () { 
    if (knobPreviousValue === $input.val()) {
      return;
    }

    if (!knobEnabled) {
      $input.val(knobPreviousValue).trigger("change");
      return;
    }

    knobPreviousValue = $input.val();

    console.log($input.val()); 
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cFKh9/1/) to disable the control.
I'm still trying to find a way to enable it back

```
 $("#btnDisable").click(function(){
      $("#knob").off().prev().off();
    });
```

Comment: Hi. The enable() function was just an example. There is no such function implemented in jquery knob as of today.

Comment: Yes. I can put it as readonly by using that attribute but then I would like to remove the attribute based on user input. That is, I want the knob to become enabled dynamically.